# Fail test if a network request is made (using Nock)

Tags: javascript, node.js, nock

I have logic that conditionally makes a network request, how can I, using Nock, make a test that would fail ***if*** a network request is made? Basically asserting that 0 calls to an endpoint was made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by listening to a `"no match"` event being emitted from nock.

```
nock.emitter.on('no match', (req: any) => {
  throw new Error(`Unexpected request was sent to ${req.path}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`nock.disableNetConnect()` will throw an error if a request is made that was not previously mocked.

[Docs](https://github.com/nock/nock#enabledisable-real-http-requests)

Comment: I also read in the docs that any request to any host not 'nocked', should throw a NetConnectNotAllowedError but that does not happen to me. The test still passes even though a request to an 'unnocked' endpoint was made.

Comment: yeah.... that's a bug/misleading doc on Nock's side.

Answer (score 0):

So in your test there is now:

```
nock('foo').post('/bar').reply(200, ({ 'bar': 'foo' })
```

When you alter that in:

```
let times = 0
nock('foo').post('/bar').reply(200, ({ 'bar': 'foo' })
act(() => {
  scope.on('replied', () => {
    times += 1
  })
})
```

then inside your test you can now set the expectation:

```
await waitFor(() => expect(times).toBe(0), { timeout: 4000 })
```

and when you do expect it, that value will be 1